# Extend functionality of a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Given a module `module.js` required as such:

`const MyModule = require('module.js');`

that exports a class `Foo`, would there be any way to "extend" `Foo` with a method `bar() -> void` in a way such that any subsequent `Foo` object created may call the `bar()` method?

Something as such:

```
const MyModule = require('module.js');

MyModule.Foo.bar = () => {
   // do something
};

const obj = new Foo();
obj.bar();
```

For reference, let's say the `Foo` class is defined and implemented like this in `module.js`:

```
module.exports = class Foo {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any attribute to a class and export that class. All the substances will have that attribute.

Define class **Foo**.

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {

  }

  // define attribute inside
  a() {
    console.log('a');
  }
}

// adding attribute outside
Foo.prototype.c = () => {
  console.log('c');
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

And add another attribute in other file.

```
const Foo = require('./foo');

// define attribute in other file
Foo.prototype.b = () => {
  console.log('b');
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

And usage:

```
const Bar = require('./bar');

let foo = new Bar();

foo.a();

foo.b();

foo.c();
```

---

Or you can Define new class **Bar** which extends **Foo** and add any attribute to it:

```
const Foo = require('./foo');

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  b() {
    console.log('b');
  }
}

module.exports = Bar;
```

And use it again like:

```
const Bar = require('./bar');

let foo = new Bar();

foo.a();

foo.b();

foo.c();
```

The class `Bar` has all `Foo`'s attributes and define new attributes.